# Jersey throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, tomcat, nullpointerexception, jersey

I have a strange problem with Jersey in my Spring based application.

The application run fine on one server, but not on second server. It works fine when the request comes from a web browser, but if request comes from another application, it throws `NullPointerException`.

Here is the webservice:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces({"text/html", "text/plain"})
public Response uploadScan(@FormDataParam("img") InputStream uploadedImageStream,
                           @FormDataParam("img") FormDataContentDisposition ImageFileDetail,
                           @FormDataParam("sig") InputStream uploadedSignatureStream,
                           @FormDataParam("sig") FormDataContentDisposition SignatureFileDetail,
                           @FormDataParam("imgID") String imgId, @FormDataParam("docID") String docId) {
    logger.info("get scan to upload " + ImageFileDetail.getFileName());// line 51
```

Here is stacktrace:

```
    26.11.2011 18:33:17 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/StorageSet] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ISSetScan.SetScan.uploadScan(SetScan.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:278)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The problem is not in line with `logger.info(...)`. If I outcomment this line, then I will get the exception on next line `int nextId = -1;`.

---

**Update**: it's not the proper approach, but if I rewrite my code to take a `HttpServletRequest` as input and use Apache Commons FileUpload to parse it, then it solves the problem. But I still want to know why the previous code doesn't work.

Comment: What is the difference between the two servers? In any way, you seem not to be running the code you think you're running. Ensure that the build went flawlessly and that the proper version is been deployed. Clean the work/temp directory of the server if necessary.

Comment: Is this other application a Java application? How is it calling your app?

Comment: difference between the two servers - on the first (on witch all work) - tomcat running on port 80, on second 8080. and i use different databases on this servers (this is configured by sittings file)

Comment: i don't know anything about apps, which use my service. this apps write another company.

Comment: 2BalusC, on both servers runs same version of service.

Comment: Apparently the `multipart/form-data` parser of Jersey is broken. I'd debug and track the raw request bodies to find the difference in requests from the webbrowser and the Java application and then report it to the Jersey maintainer.